# Missing Organization Feature: Opportunity.Sharing

Tags: managed-package, sharing

When attempting to update our managed package in a subscriber org the install is failing with the following message:

> Opportunities Missing Organization Feature: Opportunity.Sharing

That makes sense, as during packaging Opportunity Sharing is forced on as an Object Requirement.

[image]

<s>I'm not 100% certain why that is forced on currently. I suspect it is related to explicitly referencing `Organization.DefaultOpportunityAccess` in the test cases.</s>
The presence of explicit references to `OpportunityShare` in the test cases is what is forcing the setting on.

**What isn't clear is what sharing settings are required in the subscriber org to meet the Organization.Sharing feature requirement?**

They currently have the Sharing Settings Organization-Wide Defaults set to **Public Read/Write** for both *Default Internal Access* and *Default External Access*. Or is the problem related to the specific Opportunity Sharing Rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you reference a custom object’s sharing object (such as
>   MyCustomObject__share) in Apex, you add a sharing model dependency to
>   your package. Set the default org-wide access level for the custom
>   object to Private so other orgs can install your package successfully.

from [Special Behavior of Components in Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_behavior.htm?search_text=Sharing)

So, if I understand correctly it should be set the default org-wide access level for the Opportunity to Private in the Salesforce org which you use for publishing package.

Comment: Setting the Opportunity Organization-Wide Defaults to private rather than "Public Read/Write" did resolve the installation issue. I've opted to make the references to `OpportunityShare` dynamic in the test cases to remove the dependency.